# Downloading and saving excel file

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

i am using: `private void get_stocks_data()
        {
            byte[] result;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

```
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/Pages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=he-IL_ds&enumTblType=AllSecurities&Columns=he-IL_Columns&Titles=he-IL_Titles&TblId=0&ExportType=1");

        using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    } while (count != 0);
                    result = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    write_data_to_excel(result);

                }
            }
        }`
```

to download the excel file,

And this method to fill the file on my computer:

```
private void write_data_to_excel(byte[] input)
    {
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("stockdata.xls");

        for (int i = 0; input.Length > i; i++)
        {
            str.WriteLine(input[i].ToString());
        }
        str.Close();
    }
```

The result is that i get a lot of numbers...
What am i doing wrong? the file i am downloadin is excel version 2003, on my computer i have 2007...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your Write_data_to_excel function
as you are using `StreamWriter.WriteLine` method it needs string,
you are passing byte as string so your binary value say 10 will be now string 10
try   `FileStream f = File.OpenWrite("stockdata.xlsx");

            f.Write(input,0,input.Length);`  this will work.

Comment: Ok, that works... but now i see that i downloading the wrong url... the page i am downloading from have a button on his buttom which should be clicked and then select excel 2003 format download... so what url should i give?the page is at tase.co.il/TASE/Products/Stocks/MarketData and the excel file is given when clicking the button on the buttom which have the excel icon, and then chosing excel 2003 (and the download start)... what url should i give? Thanks.

Comment: Actually Excel button executes one more page `javascript:customWindowOpen('/TASE/Pages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=none&enumTblType=allShares&Columns=noneColumns&Titles=noneTitles&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={727FE319-7530-460E-9444-E9FB85BCF378}&ExportType=1', '_blank', 'scrollbars=yes; toolbar=yes; menubar=yes; resizable=yes', 800, 450);return false;`
so you should call '/TASE/Pages/ExcelExport.aspx' with all argument as above, but you have to find to parameter (GridID and CurGuid) each time when you want to call the page.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you use [`WebClient.DownloadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) instead.

This is a higher level method that will abstract from creating the request manually, dealing with encoding, etc.

Comment: Ok, using WebClientgives gives some prograss... but i am not downloading the right url... the page i am downloading from have a button on his buttom which should be clicked and then select excel 2003 format download... so what url should i give?the page is at http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/Products/Stocks/MarketData/ and the excel file is given when clicking the button on the buttom which have the excel icon, and then chosing excel 2003 (and the download start)... what url should i give?

Comment: In my case the URL was http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/Pages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=none&enumTblType=allShares&Columns=noneColumns&Titles=noneTitles&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={0BDA5110-EF93-44CB-A0F0-468C6F502B51}&ExportType=1, but it seems to contain some sort of session token so there might be more to it than just retrieving the URL